# Trappable error 0xC0000005

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic, crash, iis-6

We have one very old legacy application written on Classic ASP. Recently on a couple of servers we've started to get fatal errors. IIS process crashes. We've got few error's stack traces with IIS Debug Tool. There is 2 common types of errors.

We are using only few types of COM components in our application: ADO, Scripting.Dictionary, Scripting.FileSystem & MSXML6.

IIS logs says that error description is **access violation exception (0xC0000005)**.

Do you have any ideas about the reason of errors or any ways for future debugging. Any ways to get more info about this errors will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Stack traces:

**1.**

```
1996e18
oleaut32!VariantCopy+173
oleaut32!SafeArrayCopyData+14e
oleaut32!SafeArrayCopy+e3
oleaut32!VariantCopy+5b
oleaut32!VariantCopyInd+1a1
asp!CComponentObject::GetVariant+27
asp!CApplnVariants::get_Item+da
oleaut32!DispCallFunc+16a
oleaut32!CTypeInfo2::Invoke+234
asp!CDispatchImpl<IVariantDictionary>::Invoke+55
oleaut32!CTypeInfo2::Invoke+58a
asp!CDispatchImpl<IApplicationObject>::Invoke+55
vbscript!IDispatchInvoke2+b2
vbscript!IDispatchInvoke+59
vbscript!InvokeDispatch+13a
vbscript!InvokeByName+42
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+22b2
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51
vbscript!CSession::Execute+c8
vbscript!COleScript::ExecutePendingScripts+144
vbscript!COleScript::SetScriptState+14d
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::TryCall+19
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::Call+31
asp!CallScriptFunctionOfEngine+5b
asp!ExecuteRequest+17e
asp!Execute+24c
asp!CHitObj::ExecuteChildRequest+12c
asp!CErrInfo::LogCustomErrortoBrowser+28a
asp!CErrInfo::LogErrortoBrowserWrapper+8b
asp!CErrInfo::LogError+77
asp!HandleError+100
asp!HandleErrorMissingFilename+ac
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::Call+a7
asp!CallScriptFunctionOfEngine+5b
asp!ExecuteRequest+17e
asp!Execute+24c
asp!CHitObj::ViperAsyncCallback+3f0
asp!CViperAsyncRequest::OnCall+92
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::STAActivityWorkHelper+32
ole32!EnterForCallback+c4
ole32!SwitchForCallback+1a3
ole32!PerformCallback+54
ole32!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+159
ole32!CObjectContext::DoCallback+1c
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::DoWork+12d
comsvcs!CSTAThread::DoWork+18
comsvcs!CSTAThread::ProcessQueueWork+37
comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+190
msvcrt!_endthreadex+a3
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

**2.**

```
scrrun!FreeList+f   
scrrun!VBADictionary::~VBADictionary+28   
scrrun!VBADictionary::`scalar deleting destructor'+d   
scrrun!VBADictionary::Release+17   
oleaut32!VariantClear+b1   
oleaut32!ReleaseResources+98   
oleaut32!_SafeArrayDestroyData+4d   
oleaut32!_SafeArrayDestroy+b3   
oleaut32!SafeArrayDestroy+f   
oleaut32!VariantClear+75   
vbscript!VAR::Clear+a6   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Cleanup+63   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+8d  
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51  
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+1e02 
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62  
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+1e02  
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62   
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+1e02   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62   
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::RunNoEH+1e02   
vbscript!CScriptRuntime::Run+62   
vbscript!CScriptEntryPoint::Call+51   
vbscript!CSession::Execute+c8  
vbscript!COleScript::ExecutePendingScripts+144  
vbscript!COleScript::SetScriptState+14d  
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::TryCall+19   
asp!CActiveScriptEngine::Call+31   
asp!CallScriptFunctionOfEngine+5b   
asp!ExecuteRequest+17e  
asp!Execute+24c   
asp!CHitObj::ViperAsyncCallback+3f0   
asp!CViperAsyncRequest::OnCall+92   
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::STAActivityWorkHelper+32   
ole32!EnterForCallback+c4   
ole32!SwitchForCallback+1a3   
ole32!PerformCallback+54   
ole32!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+159   
ole32!CObjectContext::DoCallback+1c   
comsvcs!CSTAActivityWork::DoWork+12d   
comsvcs!CSTAThread::DoWork+18   
comsvcs!CSTAThread::ProcessQueueWork+37   
comsvcs!CSTAThread::WorkerLoop+190   
msvcrt!_endthreadex+a3
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+34
```

Comment: You don't say whether the errors are intermittent or constant. This would help. Also being a legacy app it was probably written for Server 2000/3 in 32 bit mode. Are you running on 2008R2 or 64-bit ? Anyway, the term "HandleErrorMissingFilename" would seem to point to file access. I always suspect file permissions when a Windows server is throwing out odd errors. In a test environment you could try making the local web accounts administrators to see if that removes the problem.

Comment: This error frequently appears about 6 times in a day. It's running on Windows Server 2003 R2 in 32 bit mode. We've already add IUSR to Admins group. This error is not reproduced on any of ours test servers.

Answer (score 0):

We had very similar situation last couple weeks. It was very complicated to track down this issue. The problem is in OnError handler of VB6 code. There are 2 cases to reproduce:

- you do not have OnError handler, error occurs and goes directly to
  IIS
- error occurs in OnError handler and goes directly to IIS.

After ~100 such errors IIS will fail to work normally. It will be absolutely unpredictable behavior after this moment.